# ReactJs: useEffect default type assignment error

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I am trying to set a `type` to a `useState` default value.

```js
...

export default () => {
    const [dropdowns, setDropdowns] = useState({
        websites: [{ label: String, value: Number }],
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        setDropdowns({
            websites: [
                {
                    label: 'Google.com',
                    value: 1,
                },
            ],
        });

        // TODO: Write clean function after api implementation is complete
        return () => {};
    }, []);

    ...
};
```

Why am I getting this error..?

[image]

Comment: Hi, I want to know clearly your question. you defined type ```dropdownType = [{ value: String; label: String }];``` value is string. however you trying to add value is number ``` {value:1, label: 'Google.com'}```

Comment: Sorry for that, I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: pls define correct types and update data that you defined data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### that showing errros bc of your data type is wrong

pls define correct types & update data like that you defined.

pls define type

```
type dropdownType = { value: String; label: String };

type stateType = {
  websites: dropdownType[];
};
```

```
const [dropdowns, setDropdowns] = useState<stateType>({
    websites: []
  });
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    setDropdowns({
      websites: [
        {
          label: "Google.com",
          value: "1"
        }
      ]
    });
```

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-mahavira-dw98wq?file=/src/App.tsx:289-431)

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I learnt a something new today. I will also post my working code snippet shortly so anyone else in need can be helped. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Yewin, here is my final working code snippet.

```js
...

type dropdownsType = {
    websites: { value: Number; label: String }[];
    accountTypes: { value: Number; label: String }[];
    statuses: { value: Boolean; label: String }[];
};

export default () => {
    const [dropdowns, setDropdowns] = useState<dropdownsType>({
        websites: [],
        accountTypes: [],
        statuses: [],
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        setDropdowns({
            websites: [{ label: 'Google.com', value: 1 }],
            statuses: [
                { label: 'Active', value: true },
                { label: 'Inactive', value: false },
            ],
            accountTypes: [
                { label: 'Developer', value: 1 },
                { label: 'Personal', value: 2 },
                { label: 'Professional', value: 3 },
            ],
        });

        // TODO: Write clean function after api implementation is complete
        return () => {};
    }, []);
}
```